# SQL Query that counts the members of each group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a table with details given as :

```
Assignment_name  organization   location  position    owner

1                 xyz            delhi     staff        ABC 
2                 GDH            Lucknow   Sr. Mgr      ABC
3                 GDRT           Kerala    Staff        AEZ
4                 xyz            delhi     staff        AEZ
5                 GDH            Lucknow   Sr. Mgr      BZD
6                 GDRT           Kerala    Staff        BZD
```

Now i want the count of records such that i get the count of the records against each owner.

For example ,2 records against ABC owner , 2 records against AEZ and 2 against BZD.

output like

```
Count  Owner
2      ABC
2      AEZ
2      BZD
```

The following query is not working:

```
select count(distinct owner), owner
from table abc
group by owner;
```

This query is returning only 1 record for each

Answer (score 3):

I think the distinct is the problem. try something like the below.

```
select owner,count(*) from table1
group by owner
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This SQl Work Fine

```
SELECT COUNT( owner ) AS counts, owner FROM table GROUP BY owner
```